# Setting JVM maximum heap size when running Kotlin scripts?

Tags: kotlin

I'm running a Kotlin script using:

```
kotlinc -script myscript.kts
```

This does some pretty heavy data processing, and quickly runs into GC/heap space errors (e.g. `java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: GC overhead limit exceeded` or `java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space` depending on what the script processes).

Is there a way to increase the JVM heap size when running Kotlin scripts? An attempt to use:

```
kotlinc -Xmx8g -script myscript.kts
```

gives the warning:

```
warning: flag is not supported by this version of the compiler: -Xmx8g
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

After taking a look at the actual `kotlinc` bash script, the heap sizing options are set based on an environment variable by the line:

```
[ -n "$JAVA_OPTS" ] || JAVA_OPTS="-Xmx256M -Xms32M"
```

Setting this environment variable before executing the kotlin script works to increase the heap size.

For the example above, the following works on Linux/MacOs:

```
$ export JAVA_OPTS="-Xmx8g"
$ kotlinc -script myscript.kts
```

On Windows:

```
set JAVA_OPTS="-Xmx8g"
```

Comment: You can put this in a shebang in the start of the script, e.g:  ```#!/usr/bin/env -S JAVA_OPTS="-Xmx8g" kotlinc -script --```